# redefine __and__ operator

Tags: python, operators, redefine, and-operator

Why I can't redefine the `__and__` operator?

```
class Cut(object):
      def __init__(self, cut):
         self.cut = cut
      def __and__(self, other):
         return Cut("(" + self.cut + ") && (" + other.cut + ")")

a = Cut("a>0") 
b = Cut("b>0")
c = a and b
print c.cut()
```

I want `(a>0) && (b>0)`, but I got b, that the usual behaviour of `and`

Comment: b = cut("b>0")  should be Cut (uppercase)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`__and__` is the binary (bitwise) `&` operator, not the logical `and` operator.

Because the `and` operator is a short-circuit operator, it can't be implemented as a function.  That is, if the first argument is false, the second argument isn't evaluated at all.  If you try to implement that as a function, both arguments have to be evaluated before the function can be invoked.

Comment: Note that you *could* allow overloading of `and` with short circuiting by providing a more complex interface, as has been suggested for Python (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/), though it is not supported.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that PEP.

Answer (score 1):

because you cannot redefine a keyword (that's what `and` is) in Python. `__add__` is used to do something else:

> [These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (...`&`...](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)

Comment: According to this weird distinction of keyword and operator, it shouldn't be possible to redefine `in`. But `__contains()__` is perfectly valid...